ue5 multiplayer update only on the server
I am experimenting with multiplayer basics in the ue5 blueprint .
I have created a custom player controller and a custom playerstate .
in the playerstate i have added a replicated float variable called health .
In the player controller ,  I have created a "run on server" rpc that just gets the player state and increments the health value .
Also i have added an umg that bind and display the health value on screen
I am testing with a liseten/server option and 3 clients .
If i call the rpc from any window , it updates only the health value on the server and not on the caller player .
Any idea on what's going on?

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

Solved :
i was getting the wrong playerstate with the node "Get PLayer state" with index 0 wich give the first playerstate in the playerarray on the server .
instead i had to use the playercontroller->Getplayerstate wich give the correct one .
i have learned something today :)
